# How to show the current value in searchLength in react js?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a code like this-

```
const [searchLength, setSearchLength] = useState(0);

function search_users () {
    Axios.get(url + '?username_like=' + searchString)
    .then(function (response) {
        setSearchLength(response.data.length);
        console.log(response.data.length);
    })
```

But in console it is always showing the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the setState function is asyncronous . Try this:

```
const [searchLength, setSearchLength] = useState(0);

function search_users () {
    Axios.get(url + '?username_like=' + searchString)
    .then(previousSearchLength=>setSearchLength(response.data.length));
     console.log(response.data.length);
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you kindly tell where do I write this?

Comment: @BoidurjaTalukdar check it out, I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

### **[Reactjs state update is batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and asynchronous it will not be updated within the same function**

If you want to see the latest value of your `searchLength` then put it inside a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(searchLength);
});
```

Or simply log it before `return()` function of your component:

```
const YourComponent = () => {

   console.log(searchLength);
   
   return(
   ...
   )
}
```